# Get DOM of SVG residing in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, svg

I have an iframe that has an SVG embedded in it. The SVG is generated by GraphViz so I can't change much in it. What I need is access to the SVG DOM in the parent page.

The source of the iframe is

```
<iframe id='graph' src='gen-graph.php' />
```

Any hints on how I can get access to the different nodes (text, polygon) etc of the SVG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) that reaches into an external svg document from the parent document.

What you're looking for is the iframe's contentDocument, which can be accessed via `yourIFrameElement.contentDocument`. Then use contentDocument as you'd use the normal `document` object.